# why am i getting unsupported operand type(s) error in python

Tags: python, operands

Hopefully this doesnt drop my rating its a simple question.

I have been trying to utilize this working code into a new program and am literally not changing a thing yet now i am getting an error this is the working code.

```
import random

def nzdExRateRand():
    return round(random.random() * (1.505 - 1.101) + 1.101, 3)

def usdExRateRand():
    return round(random.random() * (0.909 - 0.750) + 0.750, 3)

def convert(amount, exchange_rate):
    return amount * exchange_rate

exRate1 = nzdExRateRand()
exRate2 = usdExRateRand()
amount1 = 1000
amount2 = 1200

print (exRate1)
print (exRate2)
result = convert(amount1, exRate1)
print('Result:', result)
result = convert(amount2, exRate2)
print('Result:', result)
```

This is the code i am trying to do.

```
import random

#define variables

amt1 = (1000)
amt2 = ()
prevAmt1 = ()
prevAmt2 = ()

#create random exchange rates
def exRt1():
    return round(random.random() * (1.399 - 1.001) + 1.001, 3) 

def exRt2():
    return round(random.random() * (0.999 - 0.699) + 0.699, 3)

#assign exchange rates to variables

rate1 = exRt1()
rate2 = exRt2()

#create a conversion function

def convert(amount, exchange_rate):
    return amount * exchange_rate

trd1Amt = convert(amount1, exRt2)

print(trd1Amt)
```

Yet now i am getting the error.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'

I have looked at some other answers and they have not helped answer my question any help would be apprecited.

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: Please copy-paste the complete error message, include the traceback, so that we can see the precise location of the error.

Comment: `trd1Amt = convert(amount1, exRt2)` -> `trd1Amt = convert(amount1, rate2 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
trd1Amt = convert(amount1, exRt2)
```

`exRt2` is a function. If you want its RESULT, you should **call** it:

```
trd1Amt = convert(amount1, exRt2())
```

Answer (score 4):

You define exRt2 as a function

When you call

```
convert(amount1, exRt2)
```

it's going to try to return amount1 * exRt2

By doing this, you get a type mismatch because exRt2 is a function not a number, and python does not know how to multiply a number (amount1) by a function (exRt2)

you probably mean

```
convert(amount1, exRt2())
```

So the convert function will be called with as an argument the value returned by exRt2 instead of the function itself

Comment: yeah this is what i want will the exRt2 always be a new random?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
trd1Amt = convert(amount1, exRt2)
```

to

```
trd1Amt = convert(amount1, rate2 )
```

This is because earlier you save the value returned by exRt2() to the variable rate2:

```
rate2 = exRt2()
```